# Why am I getting CLIENT_ERROR when uploading a photo to LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api, php-curl

I'm working on making an Image Share with the LinkedIn v2 api. There are three steps, according to [the LinkedIn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#create-an-image-share).

1. Register your image to be uploaded.
2. Upload your image to LinkedIn.
3. Create the image share.

After I complete step 2, I check the status of the upload with  /v2/assets/{asset-id} and get a "CLIENT_ERROR". I have no idea what this means and haven't found much about it in the LinkedIn docs or online. It may have something to do with uploading a binary image file as LinkedIn asks, but as far as I know I am uploading one.

Edit: The php-curl I'm using to upload the image is below. The $uploadUrl is obtained from the image register (step 1.)

```
    $data = [
        'file' => curl_file_create($file, $mimeType)//;
    ];

    ob_start();
    $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $ch = curl_init($uploadUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'curl/7.35.0');

    $authorizationHeader = trim("Authorization: Bearer $accessToken");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorizationHeader,"Content-Type: {$mimeType}","X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0"));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, '1L');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    fclose($out);
    $debug = ob_get_clean();
    print_r($debug);

    $resp_obj = json_decode($response);
    print_r($response);
    curl_close($ch);
```

The assets API is returning:

```
> GET /v2/assets/{redacted} HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: api.linkedin.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer {redacted}

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-LI-ResponseOrigin: RGW
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 1.0.0
< Content-Length: 319
< Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2019 14:09:18 GMT
< X-Li-Fabric: prod-ltx1
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Li-Pop: prod-edc2-nkernB
< X-LI-Proto: http/1.1
< X-LI-UUID: {redacted}
< Set-Cookie: {redacted}
< X-LI-Route-Key: {redacted}
```

Response object is:

```
(
[serviceRelationships] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [identifier] => urn:li:userGeneratedContent
                [relationshipType] => OWNER
            )

    )

[recipes] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [recipe] => urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image
                [status] => CLIENT_ERROR
            )

    )

[mediaTypeFamily] => STILLIMAGE
[created] => 1553090957146
[lastModified] => 1553090958505
[id] => {redacted}
[status] => ALLOWED
)
```

**Update**: it works fine when I upload the image using command line curl:

```
curl -i --upload-file {file} --header "Authorization: Bearer {auth}" {url}
```

**Update**: Solution:

**use file_get_contents**:   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents({path-to-your-image));**

```
    $ch = curl_init($uploadUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'curl/7.35.0');
    $authorizationHeader = trim("Authorization: Bearer $accessToken");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorizationHeader,"Content-Type: {$mimeType}","X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents({path-to-your-image));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: How are you uploading your image? What HTTP response and headers do you receive from the /assets API?

Comment: Update: it works fine when I upload the image using command line curl: (curl -i --upload-file {file} --header "Authorization: Bearer {auth} {url}

Comment: For me, the `CLIENT_ERROR` status was fixed by providing the correct `Content-Type` header when uploading the file. This doesn't appear to fix OP's problem, but it might help someone else!

Answer (score 1):

**This:   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents({path-to-your-image));**

```
    $ch = curl_init($uploadUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'curl/7.35.0');
    $authorizationHeader = trim("Authorization: Bearer $accessToken");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorizationHeader,"Content-Type: {$mimeType}","X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents({path-to-your-image));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

add headers to your code as `Content-Type:application/octet-stream`

Answer (score -1):

Authorization': Bearer ${ access_token },

'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',

'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'

body is simply the image file contents or a BLOB

method: POST or PUT... i guess one of it works with some and the second for others